# Exiting from Schiphol airport while in transit

Tags: schengen, transit, layovers, canadian-citizens, ams

I am a Canadian Citizen and travelling to India from Canada. I have a lay over at Schiphol airport for 3 hours. Will it be possible for me to go outside to meet my university batch mate for half an hour. Or alternatively which will be the best place on the airport for us to meet.

Comment: I suggest that *before* you exit from the secured area, look at the length of the line to get back in. If the line is long or moving slowly, don't take the risk of missing your connection. Plan to be back in the airport before the scheduled *boarding* time for your flight (not the *departure* time).

Answer (score 2):

As a Canadian citizen, you can enter the Schengen area for up to 90 days without requiring a visa, no problem there.

Your only issue will be connection time, so it might be best to arrange to meet your friend somewhere inside the airport so you will have a better chance of making your connection. You will still have to go through passport control to meet your friend.

Comment: Thank you so much Greg for the information. When you say inside the airport, where it would be? My friend won't be able to come inside secured check in area. Will it be possible for me to go out side secured checked in area?

Comment: @AshishTiwari: Of course the meeting would need to be in the part of the airport your friend can access without being a passenger himself -- that is, landside of the security boundary.

Comment: @AshishTiwari: Yes, you can visit anywhere within the Schengen area for up to six months. Of course, you only have less than three hours, so it will have be somewhere not very far. You can exit the secure area to meet your friend, but be sure to leave enough time for you to re-enter and board your next flight.

Comment: I fixed my answer to say "90 days" instead of "six months", which also applies to the previous comment which I can no longer edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. As @Greg Hewgill points out, you don't have a problem with visa. You do have to clear immigration and customs leaving the secure area to go landside, and clear security and immigration when going back airside. On busy days, this may take significant time.

Schiphol does have several restaurants/bars/coffee shops (regular coffee shops, not the ones you go to for weed) both on the ground level (entrance) and on the upper floors (above departures), so there's a choices of places to meet.

I do not recommend meeting outside of the airport, given that you only have a 3 hour layover, that would cutting it very thin.

Comment: I'd say that 3 hours is too short on a busy day, just enough on a quiet day.